# Issues with AWS CloudWatchEvents PutRuleRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, job-scheduling, aws-java-sdk

I am in the process of writing a simple program where I want to execute a job only 1 time. I looked at Amazon's Cloudwatch events and, couples with AWS Lambda, this fits nicely with my requirement.

Im using the Java AWS SDK (version `1.11.711`) to create rules dynamically from the code.

Here is my pseudo code to generate a PutResultRequest :

```
        final PutRuleRequest putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest().withName("new_rule_name").withDescription("my first rule")
                                                                  .withScheduleExpression("0 11 24 * ? 2020").withState(RuleState.ENABLED);
```

This cron expression is shown as *Invalid* on cronmaker but shows me next execution date when I put this in cloudwatch schedule on the UI.

Cronmaker : [image]

Cloudwatch : [image]

The SDK gives me an error for even this expression `0 17 24 * ? 2020`

Stack trace of the errors is as follows -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.model.AmazonCloudWatchEventsException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: dd5dc5fb-a209-4ddb-ad58-4e468843149d)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1742)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1347)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1127)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:752)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.doInvoke(AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.java:2685)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.java:2652)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.java:2641)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.executePutRule(AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.java:2031)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatchevents.AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.putRule(AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient.java:2002)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63315', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Hey there, I'm new to this. Can you please tell me how can I pass parameters to the targeted lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try -

.withScheduleExpression("cron(0 11 24 * ? 2020)")

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-rule.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatchevents/model/PutRuleRequest.html